# PouchDb to CouchDb replication with authentication header

Tags: angularjs, couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to authenticate a user against a CouchDB via auth header with the following code:

```
 //Business Logic - do your stuff here.
                var db = getdatabaseInstanse(localDb);
                var handler = db
                    .replicate
                    .from(remoteDb, {
                        filter: function (doc) {
                            return angular.isUndefined(doc._deleted) || doc._deleted !== true;
                        }
                    });


                handler
                    .on('complete', function (info) {
                        resolved({ 'Instans': db, 'Info': info, 'PouchDb': localDb, 'CouchDb': remoteDb });
                    })
                    .on('error', function (err) {
                        if (err.status !== 500) {
                            //Ignore Couch database error 500 - since it's unknown!
                            rejected({ 'Instans': db, 'Error': err, 'PouchDb': localDb, 'CouchDb': remoteDb });
                        }
                    });
```

How do I implement it in the above mentioned example. TIA

Comment: Can you please specify better what is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do something like this ... 

                    var handler = db
                        .replicate
                        .from(remoteDb, {
                            filter: function (doc) {
                                return angular.isUndefined(doc._deleted) || doc._deleted !== true;
                            },
                            header : {'authentication': 'Basic abcxyz'}
                        });

In other words I'm trying to parse my credentials with the settings before starting the replication!

Comment: ... in other words - the remoteDb has a username/password defined and due to that I need some sort of authorization before replication can start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the auth.username and auth.password options, as outlined in the [PouchDB documentation](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_database). This would get you a db with correct authentication:

`var remoteDb = new PouchDB('http://path.to/remotedb', {auth: {username: 'user', password: 'pass'}});`

By the way, a simpler filter function would suffice in your case: `filter: function (doc) { return !doc._deleted; }`

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need create **remoteDb** instance with auth options.
Or place username and password in url like *http://username:password@domainname*